# Why `array[array.length] = elem;` fails for appending to a dynamic storage array in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, storage, arrays, mapping

Consider the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: WTFPL

contract Demo {
    uint256[] public numbers;
    
    function append(uint256 num) public {
        numbers[numbers.length] = num;
    }
}
```

When trying to execute append(..), the execution reverts. As in the following tx:
https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/kovan/0x919d409ba863c640181af55db3b1576e7c6bb8367a4472f554499d9510029e07

After doing some digging, I found out the error was somehow related to using `numbers.length` as the index. I finally discovered `array.push(..)` that ended up working just fine:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
// SPDX-License-Identifier: WTFPL
    
contract Demo {
    uint256[] public numbers;
    
    function append(uint256 num) public {
        numbers.push(num);
    }
}
```

I'm still curious why the first code block fails, while the second one works just fine.

Comment: For a reasonable language trying to access a position that doesn't exists is an error. For languages where positions start at 0 this `numbers[numbers.length]` should cause an error. Javascript isn't a reasonable language and has a lot of pitfalls, don't be like javascript (or ecmascript).